# sending info to Arduino with pyserial(opreate stepper motor)

Tags: python, c, user-interface, arduino

I'm trying to control a stepper motor that is connected to an Arduino and CNC shield using pySerial.

I succeeded to run the motor by sending characters to the serial interface. Now I want to choose the number of spins, but I haven't been able to.

I'm using Tkinter for my GUI.

Here is my Python code:

```
import serial  # Import Serial Library
from Tkinter import *
import time

usbport = 'COM3'
serial_begin_is = 9600
arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial(usbport, serial_begin_is)  # Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData


class GUI():
    def __init__(self, root):
        # type: (object) -> object
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("750x600")
        self.root.title("motor")
        self.CreateWidgets()
        self.spin = 0
        self.num = 1

    def CreateWidgets(self):
        self.number_of_spins = 1.0
        self.spin_num = 0.0
        self.speed_val = StringVar()
        self.spin_num_entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.spin_num)
        self.spin_num_entry.place(x=200, y=20)
        self.speed_num_chose = Label(self.root, text="enter spin numbers:")
        self.speed_num_chose.place(x=50, y=20)
        self.enter_spin_num = Button(self.root, text="enter", command=lambda: self.set())
        self.enter_spin_num.place(x=200, y=45)
        # self.speed_num_label = Label(self.root, text="spin num will be" +str(self.number_of_spins))
        # self.speed_num_label.place(x=255, y=45)
        self.speed_num_entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.speed_val)
        self.speed_num_label = Label(self.root, text="spin num will be: " + str(self.number_of_spins))
        self.speed_num_label.place(x=255, y=45)
        self.run_b = Button(self.root, text="run", command=lambda: self.run(self.number_of_spins))
        self.run_b.place(x=255, y=85)
        # self.run_b.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.spin_num_B = Button(self.root, text="stop", command=lambda: self.send_stop())
        self.spin_num_B.place(x=255, y=150)
        self.quit_b = Button(self.root, text="quit", command=lambda: root.destroy())
        self.quit_b.place(x=50, y=500)

    def set(self):
        self.number_of_spins = int(self.spin_num_entry.get())
        self.speed_num_label.config(text="spin num will be: " + str(self.number_of_spins))

        self.run_b.config(state=NORMAL)
    def run(self, x):
        x = int(x)
        print x
        # for i in xrange(x):
        arduinoSerialData.write(x)
        arduinoSerialData.write(b'r')

        print "run"

    def send_stop(self):
        arduinoSerialData.write(b's')
        print "stop"


root = Tk()
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

and here is my Arduino code:

```
        int cnt = 0 ;
        long spin=0;
float num = 1.0 ;
float speed1 = 100;
char start ='s';
bool prt = false;
int flag =0;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
#define stepPin 4
#define dirPin 7
#define enable 8


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

if (Serial.available()>0){
start = char(Serial.read());
   if (start == 'r')
    prt = true;
    if (prt){
     start = char(Serial.read());
    if (start!='r'&&start!='s')
         num = int(start);     
    while(spin <200*32*num){
      start = char(Serial.read());
      if (start =='s'){
        digitalWrite(enable, HIGH); 
        prt = false;
        spin = 200*32*num;
      }
          move();
          spin++;
  }
  prt = false;
  spin = 0;
    }

  if (start == 's'){ 
    pinMode(enable, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(enable, HIGH);
  }
}
}


void move () {
  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enable, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(enable, LOW);
  digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(speed1); 

}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? Is it the Tinker interface or serial communication?

Comment: I want to set the number of spin with the gui ,I sending the x as integer but the aduino doesn't get it

Comment: @Sma maybe i send a string spearted by coma and then do a split ?

Comment: I don't think sending comma separated string will make your work easier, as i think you are sending symbols of 1byte length. And i would suggest putting all the `pinMode` in setup function.

Comment: @Sma you right i'v put the pinMode in  the setup function .
do you have idea how can i set the spin num ?

Answer (score 1):

okey i'v secceded to opreate the motor,and also added some other function like changing direction and controling speed.
one problem i'm facing know is that whan the user changing the speed ,the motor stop and than apllied the speed ,and that can cuase a motor a fialure if the speed is very high.(speed is given as the delay time between stepper motor steps).
here is the codes,if any one has sulotion for the speed control i would be please to hear and learn :)

python code:

```
import serial  # Import Serial Library
from Tkinter import *
import time

usbport = 'COM3'
serial_begin_is = 38400
arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial(usbport, serial_begin_is,timeout=0.5)  # Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData


    class GUI():
        def __init__(self, root,arduinoSerialData):
            # type: (object) -> object
            self.root = root
            self.root.geometry("750x600")
            self.root.title("motor")
            self.CreateWidgets()
            self.spin = 0
            self.num = 1
            self.arduinoSerialData=arduinoSerialData
            self.flag = True;

        def CreateWidgets(self):
            self.number_of_spins = 0
            self.speed_value = 150
            self.spin_num = StringVar()
            self.speed_val = StringVar()
            self.spin_num_entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.spin_num)
            self.spin_num_entry.place(x=200, y=20)
            self.spin_num_chose = Label(self.root, text="enter spin numbers:")
            self.spin_num_chose.place(x=50, y=20)
            self.enter_spin_num = Button(self.root, text="enter", command=lambda: self.set())
            self.enter_spin_num.place(x=200, y=45)
            # self.spin_num_label = Label(self.root, text="spin num will be" +str(self.number_of_spins))
            # self.spin_num_label.place(x=255, y=45)
            self.speed_label = Label(text="speed val will be:"+str(self.speed_value))
            self.speed_label.place(x=550,y=75)
            self.speed_b = Button(self.root, text="enter", command=lambda: self.speed_set())
            self.speed_b.place(x=550, y=45)
            self.speed_num_entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.speed_val)
            self.speed_num_entry.place(x=550, y=20)
            self.speed_num_chose = Label(self.root, text="enter speed value:")
            self.speed_num_chose.place(x=420, y=20)
            self.spin_num_label = Label(self.root, text="spin num will be: " + str(self.number_of_spins))
            self.spin_num_label.place(x=255, y=45)
            self.run_b = Button(self.root, text="run", command=lambda: self.run())
            self.run_b.place(x=255, y=85)
            self.run_b.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.spin_num_B = Button(self.root, text="stop&reset", command=lambda: self.send_stop())
            self.spin_num_B.place(x=255, y=150)
            self.quit_b = Button(self.root, text="quit", command=lambda: root.destroy())
            self.quit_b.place(x=50, y=500)
            self.dir_b = Button(self.root, text="change direction", command=lambda: self.dirf())
            self.dir_b.place(x=295, y=85)

        def set(self):
            self.number_of_spins = int(self.spin_num_entry.get())
            self.data = [b"s"]
            #self.arduinoSerialData.write(self.data)
            value = list(str(self.number_of_spins))
            for char in value:
                self.data.append(char.encode())
            print self.data
            self.spin_num_label.config(text="spin num will be: " + str(self.number_of_spins))
            self.run_b.config(state=NORMAL)
        def run(self):
            run_char= "r"
            self.data[0] = run_char.encode()
            print self.data
            self.arduinoSerialData.write(self.data)
            print "run"
            self.spin_num_entry.delete(0, END)

        def send_stop(self):
            stop = "s"
            self.data[0] =stop.encode()
            self.arduinoSerialData.write(self.data)
            print self.data
            self.arduinoSerialData.close()
            self.arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial(usbport, serial_begin_is)
            self.speed_label.place_forget()
            self.speed_label.config(text="speed val will be:" +str(self.speed_value))
            self.speed_label.place(x=550, y=75)
            time.sleep(0.05)

        def dirf(self):
            print "direction had been chaged "
            self.arduinoSerialData.write(b"d")
        def speed_set(self):
            self.speed_label.place_forget()
            self.speed_label.config(text="speed val will be:"+self.speed_num_entry.get())
            self.speed_label.place(x=550, y=75)
            self.speed_in_int = int(self.speed_num_entry.get())
            self.data_speed = [b"v"]
            value = list(str(self.speed_in_int))
            for char in value:
                self.data_speed.append(char.encode())
            print self.data_speed
            self.arduinoSerialData.write(self.data_speed)


    root = Tk()
    GUI(root,arduinoSerialData)
    root.mainloop()
```

Arduino code:

```
int cnt = 0 ;
long spin=0;
float num = 1.0 ;
float speed1 = 150;
char start ;
bool prt = false;
bool dirf = true;
int flag =0;
String data[2];
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(38400);
#define stepPin 4
#define dirPin 7
#define enable 8
 pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(enable, OUTPUT);  
 digitalWrite(enable, HIGH); 
 digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  while(Serial.available()>0){
   if (Serial.peek() == 'r') {
      prt = true;  
      Serial.read();
      num = Serial.parseInt();
      //Serial.println(num);
   }
    if (prt){

    while(spin <200*32*num){   
      move();
      spin++;
      if (Serial.peek() == 's') {
          Serial.read();
          digitalWrite(enable, HIGH); 
          prt = false;
          spin = 200*32*num;
        }
      if (Serial.peek() == 'd') {
         Serial.read();
         dirf = !dirf;
         dir();
         Serial.read();
      }
       if (Serial.peek() == 'v') {
         Serial.read();
         speed1 = Serial.parseInt(); 
         Serial.read();
      }
     }
    prt = false;
    spin = 0;
    //num = 1;
    }


  if (Serial.peek() == 's') {
    Serial.read();
    digitalWrite(enable, HIGH);
    prt = false;
    spin = 0;
    num = 1;
  }
  if (Serial.peek() == 'd') {
         dirf = !dirf;
         dir();
      }
  if (Serial.peek() == 'v') {
         Serial.read();
         speed1 = Serial.parseInt(); 
         Serial.read();
      }
}
  /*
      while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        Serial.read();
      }
  */
}


void move () {
  digitalWrite(enable, LOW);
  digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(speed1); 

}
void dir (){

   if (dirf)
      digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
  else
     digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);

}
```